# Borel Slice Property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B$ be a Borel set in $R^2$. (Borel set means a set that can be obtained from union/intersection/complement of countable many open sets).

Prove that $B(y) = \left\{x | (x, y) \in B\right\}$ is also a Borel set.

My approch :

Consider a cover of $B$ by open/closed sets (countable), then all $x's$ at any given height $y$ must be contained in some subset of these sets and the subset of a countable set is countable therefore $B(y)$ is Borel set.

Is this correct?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here about what Borel sets look like. In general a Borel set could be the intersection of countably many sets, each of which is a union of countably many sets, some of which are intersections of countably many open sets while others are complements of such sets. What I've written here is only 3 or 4 levels "deep" (as you work your way up in complexity, from open sets). In general, this depth can be any countable ordinal number.  So Borel sets are a lot more complicated than what you seem to be assuming here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest proving this by induction on Borel sets.  That is, consider the family $\mathcal F$ of sets $B\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ that have the property you want, namely that all slices of $B$ are Borel sets.  Then show that $\mathcal F$ contains all open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and that $\mathcal F$ is closed under countable unions, countable intersections, and complements.

Comment: This can be made simpler. Instead of showing that $C\in\mathcal F$ if $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is open, you could as well show that if $A,B\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb{R}}$, then $A\times B\in\mathcal F$. This condition may be easier to check.

Comment: @triple_sec Indeed, the induction can be simplified, not only in the way you mentioned but also by omitting the part about countable intersections, as these can be obtained from countable unions and complements. I chose the formulation in my answer to match the definition of "Borel set" in the question, assuming that would save the OP some checking that various definitions are  equivalent.

Comment: Fair enough. I just felt that measure theory is quite delicate in the sense of how much efficiency of proofs matters. There are many families of sets from which a given Borel algebra can be equivalently generated. I just wanted to save the OP some time, given that checking whether the family of sets I suggested satisfies the desired condition is two lines, whereas checking it for open sets is far from straightforward, to put it mildly. So much so that I feel that checking whether the definitions are equivalent, the need for which you pointed out, might still be a shorter path.

Comment: @triple_sec Checking the desired condition for open sets looks easy to me. Sections of open sets (of the plane) are open (in the line).

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes it worked, thanks a lot.